# what is Ideal size of a cell in HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

i have file contains huge blob fields size 10-15 MB each and i want to store in HBase.

any disadvantage having cell size around 10-15 MB? if yes then what should be the ideal size for column value to get the best performance in hbase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ideally less than 10 MB, if it's more you need to change your hdfs block and region sizes.

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/FAQ_Design#A3

Comment: my cluster has default hdfs block and hbase region configuration. as per solution do i need to increase the hdfs block size ?.. thanks

Comment: Yes, the FAQ says you should. (updated my answer to be clearer)